# Translating arrays in pseudocode to Python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

Hello I am trying to write a short program using the following pseudocode I can not figure out how to translate the arrays in pseudocode into Python. For example:

```
declare Names[5] as a string
```

I tried to put

```
Name[5] = string
```

but it will come up with unresolved reference I tried looking up tutorials on how to use arrays but still can't figure it out could you give me a few tips or some good videos explaining arrays

```
Main
    Call writeNammeAssn()
    Declare Names[5] As String
    Declare Sales[5] As Float
    Set Max = 0
    Set K = 0
    Set Index = 0
    Names[K] = getName()
    Sales[K] = getFloat()

    While Names[K] != "*"
        If Sales[K] > Max Then
            Set Index = K
            Set Max = Sales[Index]
        End If
        Set K = K + 1
        Names[K] = getName()
        Sales[K] = getInt()
    End While

    Write "Maximum sales for the month: " + Max
    Write "Salesperson: " + Names[Index]
End Main
```

Comment: Hello there. SO is not a code translation site. Please make an attempt first, and share your code. We'll help you debug.

Comment: [This question almost the same as yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44958366/array-in-python-using-pseudo-code) has three answers, one of them mine. One of them should suit you. Mine in particular addresses how to declare the arrays. Asking for resources like "videos explaining arrays" is explicitly off-topic for this site.

Comment: In Python, arrays, or `lists`, as they are commonly known here, don't need to be declared with their size attached to the name. They are dynamic in Python. So `names = ['Bill', 'George']` would work just like `names = []` will.

Comment: Python lists are dynamic and heterogeneous. They don't have a fixed size or type. You need to declare an empty list and `append()` elements, or put default values in the list such as `None`s.

Answer (score 0):

```
Names=5*[""]
print Names
```

result:
`['', '', '', '', '']`

```
Names[2]="test"
print Names
```

result:
`['', '', 'test', '', '']`